# JSONException: Unparsable JSON string in TipoControllerTest.updateTipoTest

Tags: java, json, spring

I am encountering an error while running a test in my TipoControllerTest class. The error message is org.json.JSONException: Unparsable JSON string and it occurs in the updateTipoTest method. Here is the stack trace:

```
error: org.json.JSONException: Unparsable JSON string: 
 at org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONParser.parseJSON(JSONParser.java:56)
 at org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONCompare.compareJSON(JSONCompare.java:50)
 at org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONCompare.compareJSON(JSONCompare.java:125)
 at org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert.assertEquals(JSONAssert.java:415)
 at org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert.assertEquals(JSONAssert.java:394)
 at org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert.assertEquals(JSONAssert.java:336)
 at org.springframework.test.util.JsonExpectationsHelper.assertJsonEqual(JsonExpectationsHelper.java:61)
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ContentResultMatchers.lambda$json$9(ContentResultMatchers.java:227)
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:212)
 at edu.icai.pat.TipoControllerTest.updateTipoTest(TipoControllerTest.java:82)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
```

Test Method (updateTipoTest):

```
@Test
public void updateTipoTest() throws Exception {
    given(tipoService.updateTipo(1L, tipo)).willReturn(tipo);

    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/tipos/1")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content("{\"id\":1, \"tipo\":\"Test tipo\", \"description\":\"Test description\"}"))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().json("{\"id\":1, \"tipo\":\"Test tipo\", \"description\":\"Test description\"}", true));
}
```

I'm trying to test the update functionality of my TipoController. The test sends a POST request to the URL /api/v1/tipos/1 with a JSON payload containing the updated Tipo object. However, it seems that the JSON string is not being parsed correctly, resulting in the JSONException.

I have already verified that the JSON string is valid, and it matches the expected response from the controller. I suspect there might be an issue with the JSON parsing or comparison libraries used in the test.

Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the exception `org.json.JSONException` seems like you use `json.org` package which is a great library to learn JSON but not really good for any real-life scenario. I would suggest to switch either to [Json-Jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson). They are the most popular and widely used. Spring framework by default should be using Jackson library.

Comment: Could you provide an example how to do it? please thanks

Comment: This is beyond the scope of SO Q and A. Plus I don't know which spring or spring boot versions are you using. Here are the artifacts I am using:
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>

    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>

            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>

All of version 2.14.0-rc2